Is there any way to connect GCP DAG Executions to SAP HANA?
In our project we want to connect GCP Dag's to make automatic executions based on some data retrieved from SAP HANA (table counts)
Basically that, anyone know any way to do this? We want the DAG's to execute only after X amount of time and checking that table counts from HANA matches on GCP
